# How to sort an array of structs with std::binary_search or std::sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stl, structure

I have a sorted array of structs. 
I want to use `std::binary_search` or `std::find` on it.

Everywhere I look, I find examples which show how to do it with a vector of structs. Never with an array of structs. I am not sure if I must use a predicate or overload the `=` operator or what.

What must be the third parameter to `std::find` if I am using the following call:

`template< class InputIt, class T >
InputIt find( InputIt first, InputIt last, const T& value );`

Also, it says that the above calls will return an Iterator or return the last. How does this work with structs. Structs don't have iterators, do they ?

Comment: It's the same with an array as a vector. If you're using C arrays, they should be `std::array`, and `std::begin` and `std::end` work regardless.

Comment: No way to do it without std::arrays ? what if I am using plain struct a[MAX] ?

Comment: *`std::begin` and `std::end` work regardless*. And for arrays, the iterator would be a pointer. Pointers meet the requirements of random-access iterators.

Comment: @chris and how to tell `std::find` which particular data item of the struct to use for comparison ? overload the `=` operator ? And what would the return value contain ? the index ?

Comment: As stated in any reference, `std::find` [uses `operator==`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), or you can use `std::find_if`. And it returns an iterator (pointer here) to the found element or `last`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to apply it to the (valid)array range `[a, b)` of an array `arr`, `InputIt` should be `std::begin(arr) + a`, and `OutputIt` should be `std::begin(arr) + b`. If `b` is equal to the number of elements in `arr`, then you can set `OutputIt` to `std::end(arr)` as well.

`std::begin` and `std::end` called on an array of type T return T*. Thus, you can always substitute T* for `InputIt` and `OutputIt` when thinking of these functions on arrays. `std::find` returns an InputIt. So, what you get is a pointer to the appropriate array element. If nothing was found, it returns `last`.

Comment: How to interpret the return value ?

Comment: @Wildling: For raw arrays of type `T`, the iterator type is pointer-to-`T`.